# Why is the kill process not working using the Exec function in my C program?

Tags: c, linux, bash, process, operating-system

I am creating my own shell (like bash) and I have a function that calls the execv function and passes in a specific process pid to kill. I basically run a sleep command for 10 seconds, and halfway through I want to kill it. But my kill command does not seem to be working. Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix it?

Below are functions related to execv

```
void run_execv(char *path, char *args[])
{
    int result = execv(path, args);
}

void kill_process(char *target_pid)
{
    char *bin_path = "/bin/kill";
    char *args[] = {bin_path, "-15", target_pid, NULL};
    run_execv(bin_path, args);
}

void ps()
{
    char *bin_path = "/bin/ps";
    char *args[] = {bin_path, NULL};
    run_execv(bin_path, args);
}
```

And the calling of the kill_process function is shown below. Basically I am calling the kill command as a child process.

```
else if (strncmp(shellInput, "pkill", strlen("pkill")) == 0 || strncmp(shellInput, "kill", strlen("kill")) == 0)
        {
            char *target_pid = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            int childStatus;
            pid_t spawnPid = fork();
            switch (spawnPid)
            {
            case -1:
                perror("fork()\n");
                exit(1);
                break;
            case 0:
                // This is the child process where we will call the ls function
                kill_process(target_pid);
                perror("execv");
                exit(2);
                break;
            default:
                // This is the parent process that takes control back after child process finishes.
                spawnPid = waitpid(spawnPid, &childStatus, 0);
                printf("CHILD STATUS: %d\n", childStatus);
                processStatus = childStatus;
                break;
            }
```

Even after killing that sleep process, it still shows up when I check my current processes running with ps. Please see my screenshot below for the same execution.

```
~/Desktop/OSU/CS-344 (Operating Systems)/assignment3(main*) » ./a.out                                                               sampai@sams-mbp-2
: ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
25223 ttys003    0:06.24 /bin/zsh -l
41134 ttys003    0:00.00 ./a.out
32018 ttys004    0:01.49 -zsh
30707 ttys005    0:00.14 /bin/zsh --login -i
: sleep 30 &
background pid is 41143
: ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
25223 ttys003    0:06.24 /bin/zsh -l
41134 ttys003    0:00.00 ./a.out
41143 ttys003    0:00.00 sleep 30
32018 ttys004    0:01.49 -zsh
30707 ttys005    0:00.14 /bin/zsh --login -i
: kill 41143
CHILD STATUS: 0
: ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
25223 ttys003    0:06.24 /bin/zsh -l
41134 ttys003    0:00.00 ./a.out
41143 ttys003    0:00.00 (sleep)
32018 ttys004    0:01.49 -zsh
30707 ttys005    0:00.14 /bin/zsh --login -i
:
```

Comment: Please show the output as text and not an image. Otherwise it makes it difficult for others to view and copy from your output. `(sleep)` the brackets indicate the process has been terminated but not reaped (ie it is a zombie process). You need to call `waitpid` on the sleep process id after killing it.

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know about that! Isn't that what I am doing in the default section of my switch statement? spawnPid = waitpid(spawnPid, &childStatus, 0);

Comment: No you are waiting for the process that is doing the killing not the process that is being killed.

Comment: Note that you don't really need to fork at all. Just call the `kill` function directly.

Comment: if I call the kill_process function directly, it does work perfectly, BUT it also ends my entire program, and I need it to continue running, meaning it has to keep prompting the user to enter in a new command. Any ideas?

Comment: Not kill_process. That calls execv which will replace the current process. I mean the [kill system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)

Comment: well the kill system call is not supported by my compiler (gcc) unfortunately.

Comment: Huh? That can't be true. That is a basic posix system call and should be supported by every Linux standard C lib. Are you sure? What makes you think that?

Comment: smallsh.c:438:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'kill' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                kill(target_pid);

Comment: Read the manual. You may be  missing an include.

Comment: You need `#include <signal.h>` to get the declaration of `kill` and all the `SIG_XXX` constants.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Basically like kaylum said in the comments, I needed to add a waitpid call outside of my switch statement. And I needed to wait on the correct pid, which I needed to get inside of the child process. Please see my updated code below.

```
int process_pid;
            pid_t spawnPid = fork();
            switch (spawnPid)
            {
            case -1:
                perror("fork()\n");
                exit(1);
                break;
            case 0:
                // This is the child process where we will call the ls function
                process_pid = getpid();
                kill_process(target_pid);
                perror("execv");
                exit(2);
                break;
            default:
                // This is the parent process that takes control back after child process finishes.
                spawnPid = waitpid(process_pid, &childStatus, 0);
                processStatus = childStatus;
                break;
            }
            spawnPid = waitpid(process_pid, &childStatus, 0); // Need this to kill zombie process.
            printf("CHILD STATUS: %d\n", childStatus);
```